# Telethon iter_messages works for one channel but not another

Tags: python, telethon

I have tried the following code which works for one channel but the other channel says "Could not find the input entity for PeerUser". Not sure why there's a difference. I think the channel still exists because when I open the channel in the browser (going to `t.me/<channel_slug>` and following the link), it sends me to the `https://web.telegram.org/z` address which has the same channel_id

```
messages_obj = client.iter_messages(int(channel_id))
```

any idea why this is?

Comment: try `channel = await client.get_entity(channel_id)` and then `messages_obj = client.iter_messages(channel)`

Answer (score 2):

By this [page](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/readthedocs/concepts/entities.rst) you need some like this:

```
# (These examples assume you are inside an "async def")
async with client:
    # Does it have a username? Use it!
    user = await client.get_profile(username)

    # Do you have a conversation open with them? Get dialogs.
    await client.get_dialogs()

    # Are they participants of some group? Get them.
    await client.get_participants('username')

    # Is the user the original sender of a forwarded message? Fetch the message.
    await client.get_messages('username', 100)

    # NOW you can use the ID anywhere!
    await client.send_message(123456, 'Hi!')

    user = await client.get_profile(123456)
    print(user)
```

> If you're here because of "Could not find the input peer for", you must ask yourself, "how did I find this user or chat through official applications"? Now do the same with the library.

So, I think that best way for you is the use string `username`.
Or find workaround

Comment: Yes, I needed to use one of these first. I wanted to be able to forget about the username and just use ID(because the username can be changed but the ID can't)...so I have joined the channels and then I do get_dialogs if the session is new and then I can just keep using the id from then on